# @Autowired filed is null in @Component class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a @Component class:

```
@Component
@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class WebSocketHandler {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllByOnlineIsTrue();
        session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(new RestResponse(Status.SUCCESSFUL, "online users", users));
        System.out.println("Open WebSocket connection...");
    }
}
```

`UserService` is an interface and it has an implementation:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate template;

    //...
}
```

When the `onOpen` method of `WebSocketHandler` was called, it threw `NullPointerException` because the `userService` was null. It's weird because I also have a controller class and `userService` is fine:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public RestResponse login(@RequestParam(name = "username") String username,
                              @RequestParam(name = "password") String password,
                              HttpServletRequest request) {
        User user = userService.findUserByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
        // ....
    }

}
```

I don't understand it. Could anyone help?

Comment: Have a look at: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/... It looks like you're using the Java EE 7 websocket Annotation with `@Component` rather than a spring compatible version.  As such, you're talking to a Java EE component that doesn't know about spring and isn't managed by spring but is instead managed by the container itself.

Comment: Oh...It seems you are right. Thank you. @Colton